# GoLang bitwise calculation

Tags: go, bitwise-operators

I have a buffer :

```
buffer := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{
        0x85, 0x02, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03,
        0x41, 0x42, 0x43,
    })
```

I am trying to return the int value of buffer[8:24]
I get

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Not sure how to shift such a large section. of the byte.

new to this. Any help would be great. my initial approach was

```
requestid := (uint64(buffer.Bytes()[8]&0xff)<<24 + uint64(buffer.Bytes()[9]&0xff)<<16 + uint64(buffer.Bytes()[10]&0xff)<<8 + uint64(buffer.Bytes()[11]&0xff.....)))
```

but this got tedious, and I know there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Is there a reason this sits in a `bytes.Buffer` as opposed to just using the `[]byte` slice directly?

Comment: Thats how it will be handed off. .. but to keep this full circle, what do you mean? Is there a better way?

Comment: It's not the buffer itself, but the way you use it in the `requestId = ` part. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the manual bit shifting and OR'ing, but your code can be cleaned up by removing all those `buffer.Bytes()` calls.

You also do not need the `&0xff` parts. What `n&0xff` does, is clear out all bits outside of the `0-255` range. Since each value in the buffer is already a byte (0-255), these operations do nothing at all. If we want to do `22 & 255`, we get the following:

```
    Hexadecimal   | Decimal     | Binary
    --------------|-------------|----------------------
x   0x16          | 22          | 00010110
y   0xff          | 255         | 11111111
    --------------|-------------|---------------------- AND (&)
    0x16          | 22          | 00010110 = x
```

As you can see, the operation has no effect at all. Replace `x` with any 8-bit value and you will see the same result. The outcome of `x & 0xff` is always `x`.

Additionally, when you assign to the `requestId`, you start by shifting by 24 bits. This tells me you are reading a 32-bit integer. Why then do you continue reading values beyond 32 bits and converting it all to a 64 bit integer?

If you are reading a 64-bit int in Big Endian, try this:

```
data := buf.Bytes()[8:]
requestid := uint64(data[0])<<56 | uint64(data[1])<<48 |
    uint64(data[2])<<40 | uint64(data[3])<<32 |
    uint64(data[4])<<24 | uint64(data[5])<<16 |
    uint64(data[6])<<8 | uint64(data[7])
```

If you are reading a 64-bit int in Little Endian, try this:

```
data := buf.Bytes()[8:]
requestid := uint64(data[7])<<56 | uint64(data[6])<<48 |
    uint64(data[5])<<40 | uint64(data[4])<<32 |
    uint64(data[3])<<24 | uint64(data[2])<<16 |
    uint64(data[1])<<8 | uint64(data[0])
```

If you are reading a 32-bit int in Big Endian, try this:

```
data := buf.Bytes()[8:]
requestid := uint32(data[0])<<24 | uint32(data[1])<<16 |
    uint32(data[2])<<8 | uint32(data[3])
```

If you are reading a 32-bit int in Little Endian, try this:

```
data := buf.Bytes()[8:]
requestid := uint32(data[3])<<24 | uint32(data[2])<<16 |
    uint32(data[1])<<8 | uint32(data[0])
```

#### binary package

Alternatively, you can use the [encoding/binary](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary) package:

```
var value uint64
err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &value)
....
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. Couple of questions.

Comment: encoding/binary has special methods for reading uints, see here: http://play.golang.org/p/CC9HeZAvRj. It will be faster than `binary.Read` since it avoids the use of reflection.

Comment: I really get this now. Thank you for the help. >> The buffer that I provided came with a key as to what the values "should" return ( according to the frame that was provided) . in the end the RequestID should == 1 . When I run your code, it only returns 0. In @logiraptors code, he uses the slice of [16:24] and that returns 1. When I asked my lead about the Big or Little Endian he stated that it didn't matter. ( jr. dev here )

Comment: Integers are stored in memory in either big- or little endian, depending on whether you run the program on linux, windows, OSX, etc. A 16-bit value `1234` might thus be represented as bytes `0x04 0xd2` or `0xd2 0x04`. Depending on how you interpret the bytes, you get either `1234` or `53764`. There is a generally accepted convention that data sent over a network is always encoded in Big Endian. But it's best to make sure this is the case.